# Getting multiple data in foreach nested loop php. How to prevent it?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code in which am fetching the post for each user, but each time the data is repeating and showing the garbage data.

```
foreach($users as $key=>$user) {
    $userid = $user->ID;
    $userdata = array();
    $user = get_userdata($userid);
    $userdata["userId"] = $user->ID;

    foreach($posts as $postKey=>$post) {
        $postdata['post_id'] = $post['id'];
        $postdata['mime-type'] = "video";
        $allposts[] = $postdata;
    }

    $status = 1;
    $message = "Data found";
}
```

This is my code mentioned above. Whats wrong. Please help

Comment: Where do you set `$allposts` to an empty array?

Comment: This is to use into the response like $response = json_encode($allposts);

Comment: what response you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean by garbage data? What is your expected output? What does the output look like now? Where does `$posts` come from?

Comment: @RohitKumarSharma its repeating the data mutiple times

Answer (score 1):

Just use the code like this.
Add the unset after your inner foreach to prevent repeation.

```
foreach($users as $key=>$user) {
$userid = $user->ID;
$userdata = array();
$user = get_userdata($userid);
$userdata["userId"] = $user->ID;
    foreach($posts as $postKey=>$post)
    {

        $postdata['post_id'] = $post['id'];
        $postdata['mime-type'] = "video";
        $allposts[] = $postdata;

    }

    $status = 1;
    $message = "Data found";
    unset($allposts);
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you @rohit